# C# Bouncy Castle FipsDRBG

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, fips

I'm trying to access a few things from FipsDRBG class.
My code is shown below. How do I access fromEntropySource()? This function is within the internal class Base in FipsDRBG.

```
MyEntropyProvider entropyProvider = new MyEntropyProvider(@params);
FipsDrbg.BuilderService shaAlgo = FipsDrbg.Sha1; // Here I tried to use FipsDrbg.Base but then again it is internal    
FipsDrbg.Builder builder = shaAlgo.fromEntropySource(entropyProvider);
```

I've compared C# FipsDrbg with Java FipsDrbg. In Java, all classes are declared public which is why I can access them easily. I can neither access FipsDrbg.Base or fromEntropySource().

Can someone please suggest how to proceed with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could access all the FIPS related code after getting a paid version of the library. It has great support for all the FIPS related functions which may or may not be available in the free version.